# Integrity Error in OpenERP

Tags: python, xml, odoo

Hello to all , I have been working on a module in OpenERP-7 and I have come across an Integrity error which is occurring on clicking the button.
         My module was working fine untill yesterday but then I made some changes in the xml view like inheriting some fields from product.product class.The xml view is working ok but the button function is giving me integrity error just after I included the inherited fields into my module.My python code is given below:

```
import time
from lxml import etree
from openerp.osv import fields, osv
from openerp import tools

class deg_form(osv.osv):

_name = "deg.form"
_inherit="product.product"
_columns = {
     'categ1':fields.many2one('product.category','Category'),       
     'categ2':fields.many2one('product.category','Category'),        
     'my_products':fields.many2one('product.product','Parent'), 
        }

def Product_Category_OnChange(self,cr,uid,ids,categ1):
    pro_id=[]
    cr.execute('select id,name from product_template where  categ_id in (select id from product_category where parent_id in (select id from product_category where parent_id='+str(categ1)+'))  union select id,name from product_template where  categ_id in (select id from product_category where parent_id='+str(categ1)+') union select id,name from product_template where categ_id='+str(categ1))
    res = cr.fetchall()
for pid,name in res:
        pro_id.append((pid))

    return {'domain':{'my_products':[('id','in',pro_id)]}}

def create_product(self,cr,uid,ids,context):
    return{          
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'res_model': 'product.product',
        'context': "{}",
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window'}

def show_product(self,cr,uid,ids,context):

    for id in ids:
       deg_obj=self.pool.get('deg.form').browse(cr,uid,id)
       my_id=int(deg_obj.my_products)

    return{
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'res_model': 'product.product',
        'res_id':my_id,
        'context': "{}",
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window'}

deg_form()
```

Here is my xml code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?><openerp>
    <data>
  <!-- ############################# MAIN FORM VIEW ######################### -->


    <record id="mywin_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">mywin.form</field>
            <field name="model">deg.form</field>          
            <field eval="7" name="priority"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="FORM DATA" version="7.0">                  
                     <h1>
                       <label for="categ1" string="Parent Category"/>
                           <field name="categ1" on_change="Product_Category_OnChange(categ1)" />
                     </h1>
                     <h1>
                       <label for="categ2" string="Child Category"/>
                           <field name="categ2"  />
                     </h1>
                              <div name="options" position="inside">
                    <field name="asset_ok"/>
                    <label for="asset_ok"/>
                <!--    <field name="asset_type" attrs="{'invisible':[]}"/>-->
                </div>                



                           <field name="asset_type"/>



<newline/>
<newline/>

                     <!-- NOEBOOK STARTED -->



         <notebook>




                                <page string="Asset Informations" attrs="{'invisible':[('asset_ok','=',False)]}">
                                    <group colspan="2" col="4" attrs="{'invisible': [('asset_type', '!=', 'phones')]}">
                                        <separator colspan="2" string="Phone Details"/>
                                        <newline/>
                                        <field name="phone_id"/>
                                        <field name="phone_data_id"/>
                                                <field name="contr_exp_phone"/>
                                                <field name="job_num_phone"/>
                                                <field name="phone_num_phone"/>
                                                <field name="person_phone"/>
                                                <field name="mgr_phone"/>
                                                <field name="remarks_phone"/>
                                                <field name="radio_phone"/>   
                                                <field name="pm_phone"/>
                                                <field name="dept_code_phone"/>

                                    </group>

                                            <group colspan="2" col="4" attrs="{'invisible': [('asset_type', '!=', 'equipment')]}">
                                        <separator colspan="2" string="Equipment Details"/>
                                        <newline/>
                                         <field name="mon_pay_equip"/>    
                                         <field name="dealer_equip"/>
                                                 <field name="insp_time_equip"/>
                                                 <field name="ins_ren_date_equip"/>  
                                                 <field name="make_equip"/>
                                                 <field name="model_equip"/>
                                                 <field name="serial_num_equip"/>
                                                 <field name="btu_equip"/>
                                                 <field name="location_equip"/>
                                                 <field name="pur_date_equip"/>
                                                 <field name="warr_equip" />
                                                 <field name="term_warr_equip"/> 
                                                 <field name="warr_contact_equip"/> 
                                                 <field name="remarks_equip"/>
                                                 <field name="issue_date_equip"/>
                                                 <field name="issue_to_equip"/>
                                                 <field name="ret_date_equip"/>
                                                 <field name="cost_equip"/>
                                                 <field name="vendour_equip"/>
                                                 <field name="equip_quant_equip"/>
                                                 <field name="inv_date_equip"/>
                                                 <field name="lease_agg_num_equip"/>   
                                                 <field name="loan_term_equip"/>
                                                 <field name="state_reg_equip"/>



                                           </group>


                                            <group colspan="2" col="4" attrs="{'invisible': [('asset_type', '!=', 'copiers')]}">
                                        <separator colspan="2" string="Copier Details"/>
                                        <newline/>
                                         <field name="mon_pay_copier"/>                     
                                                 <field name="start_date_copier"/> 
                                                 <field name="make_copier"/>
                                                 <field name="serial_num_copier"/>
                                                 <field name="excess_copy_copier"/>
                                                 <field name="quat_allow_copier"/>
                                                 <field name="term_copier"/>
                                                 <field name="reg_expdate_copier"/>
                                                 <field name="service_copier"/>
                                                 <field name="service_num_copier"/>

                                                 <field name="location_copier"/>
                                                 <field name="vendour_copier"/>
                                                 <field name="lease_agg_num_copier"/>   
                                                  <field name="remarks_copier"/>



                                           </group>








                                    <group colspan="2" col="4" attrs="{'invisible': [('asset_type', '!=', 'vehicles')]}">
                                        <separator colspan="2" string="Vehicle Details"/>
                                        <newline/>
                                        <field name="fuel_card_vehicle"/>
                                        <field name="maintain_card_vehicle"/>
                                        <field name="pass_tag_vehicle"/>
                                        <field name="stage_reg_vehicle"/>
                                        <field name="plate_vehicle"/>
                                        <field name="plate_type_vehicle"/>
                                        <field name="vin_no_vehicle"/>
                                        <field name="ls_ln_term_vehicle"/>
                                        <field name="tot_mileage_vehicle"/>
                                        <field name="monthly_payment_vehicle"/>
                                        <field name="dealer_vehicle" />
                                        <field name="reg_exp_date_vehicle"/>
                                        <field name="ins_exp_date_vehicle"/>
                                        <field name="loss_payee_vehicle"/>
                                        <field name="mileage_receipt_vehicle"/>
                                        <field name="mileage_vehicle"/>
                                        <field name="mileage_date_vehicle"/>
                                                <field name="driver_vehicle"/>
                                                <field name="unit_num_vehicle"/>
                                                <field name="probblem_vehicle"/>
                                                <field name="v_cost_vehicle"/>
                                                <field name="v_date_vehicle"/>
                                                <field name="own_type_vehicle"/>
                                     </group>
                                    <group colspan="2" col="4" attrs="{'invisible': [('asset_type', '!=', 'jackets')]}">
                                        <separator colspan="2" string="Jacket Details"/>
                                        <newline/>
                                        <field name="jack_size_id"/>
                                                <field name="name_jacket"/>
                                                <field name="title_jacket"/>
                                                <field name="supervisor_jacket"/>

                                    </group>
                                    <group colspan="2" col="4" attrs="{'invisible': [('asset_type', '!=', 'ndt')]}">
                                        <separator colspan="2" string="NDT Details"/>
                                        <newline/>

                                                <field name='equip_type_ndt'/>
                                                <field name="equip_quant_ndt"/>
                                                <field name="model_num_ndt"/>
                                                <field name="serial_num_ndt"/>
                                                <field name="pers_resp_ndt"/>
                                                <field name="last_calibration_ndt"/> 
                                        <field name="next_calibration_ndt"/>
                                        <field name="operation_ndt"/>
                                        <field name="last_review_ndt"/>
                                    </group>
                                    <separator colspan="1"  string="_________________________________________________________________" />
                                </page>



                        </notebook>



<h1> 
                       <label for="my_products" string="Products" /> 
                           <field name="my_products" />
                     </h1>

                 <button name="show_product" string="SHOW PRODUCT" type="object"/>
                 <button name="create_product" string="CREATE PRODUCT" type="object"/> 


                     <!-- NOTEBOOK ENDED -->



                </form>
            </field>
    </record>
  <!-- ############################# MAIN TREE VIEW ######################### -->
<record id="mywin_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">myform.tree</field>
            <field name="model">deg.form</field>
            <field eval="7" name="priority"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="FORM DATA" version="7.0">
                     <field name="categ1"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
</record>
  <!-- #############################  ######################### -->
<record id="mywin_new_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">New</field>
            <field name="res_model">deg.form</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="mywin_tree_view"/>   
</record>

<record id="mywin_new_form" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
            <field eval="2" name="sequence"/>       
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="mywin_form_view"/>    
            <field name="act_window_id" ref="mywin_new_action"/>
</record>

<record id="mywin_new_tree" model="ir.actions.act_window.view">
            <field eval="3" name="sequence"/>         
            <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="mywin_tree_view"/>   
            <field name="act_window_id" ref="mywin_new_action"/> 
</record>  
<!--  *****************Main Calling Menu***********************  -->    
         <menuitem id="myform" name="Search Product" sequence="1"/>
         <menuitem id="myform_menu" name="Main Menu" parent="myform" />
         <menuitem action="mywin_new_action" id="myform1_menu" name="Search Product" parent="myform_menu"/>

       </data>
</openerp>
```

The two buttons in my xml code are associated to two functions . One is returning the form view of the current product and other is returning the default product form for creating new product.The buttons on clicking are giving following error :

```
Integrity Error

The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:
- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set

[object with reference: name - name]
```

When I try to add a new button just to show a message, I still get the same integrity error.I think it is because of that inherited fields or may be something else.Please guide me to the direction so that I may be able to fix this. Thanks n Regards

Answer (score 2):

you're inheriting from `product.product`, that means all fields from `product.product` will be in your `deg.form` model and here it comes to your error.
your view xml (with typo: `categ1` is twice in it) isn't showing the required fields which come from `product.product` model. so you can't set them in your view, but they are required (eg. **name**, categ_id, type) and this will get you the error.

a way to make them not required any more is to override the required columns.

---

Integrity Error

The operation cannot be completed, probably due to the following:
- deletion: you may be trying to delete a record while other records still reference it
**- creation/update: a mandatory field is not correctly set**

[object with reference: **name - name**]

Comment: but I need only few fields of product.product . Therefore I set them in for xml view because I will use those fields to search the product

Comment: but that is how the openerp framework is working. i don't know exactly what you want to do here (over all your stackoverflow questions) but i guess you're not understanding the framework right well and therefor thinking to complex/difficult for the solution of your problem :-)

Comment: look asset_type belong to product.product and its being shown on my form. Means the field is inherited but the integrity error seems to be the problem

Comment: sorry but i'm out, you don't understand the problem here.

Comment: sorry but can you elaborate plz because I m not getting this issue

Comment: you inherit from product.product. that means you get a number of fields with it, for example: name (char, required), type (selection, required) or categ_id (many2one, required). and you have no way to set these fields in your model (which is inherited from product.product), because your view isn't showing any of these fields. so if you save a record within your view, you will get this error, because, as the error says, you don't have set the field 'name', and that field is a required field on model product.product from which deg.form inherited.

Comment: ok i get . Means some fields of product.product having required property as true , the error are because of them.

Comment: Can u please guide me to override the columns to fix this issue

Comment: you can just copy the columns (eg. name, type, etc.) from the original code to your _columns dictionary and remove the required parameter

Comment: now my class has all fields in my columns dictionary but still get the same error with reference "name" . Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: if it's name again, i don't know what problem came up now :/

Comment: yes its same error. Anyhow thanks alot . You were very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the integrity issue .I was using `inheritance by prototyping` before which was  causing error I think . Then I realized that I should use `class inheritance` because I dont need all the fields of the parent class. For that we have to be careful to set the values  `_name == _inherit.`